# Using nginx in front of node.js app?

Tags: node.js, nginx, web

I'm trying to create a website that will basically be my own custom "profile."

On this server, I have a project called "gradebook" that's a node app running on port 3030...

I want the site to be set up so that when you go to www.website.com, you see my picture and list of my accomplishments/projects/etc.

If you navigate to www.gradebook.website.com, you'll see my gradebook app.

Can this functionality be accomplished using nginx?

If so, could someone point me in the right direction with this...? I'm not very good with setting this kind of stuff up so any guidance is appreciated :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can proxy you request to node app

e.g.

```
location /gradebook {
  proxy_pass        http://localhost:3030;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;      
}
```